# How do I use .bashrc command inside expect spawn command

Tags: linux, expect

I'm trying to run a custom .bashrc command within my expect script but it doesn't recognize the command. This is obvious because each script runs in its own shell, however I'm not able to `source ~/.bashrc` because it comes back with an `invalid command name "-f"`(Not sure where it gets the "-f" from). Does anyone have any recommendations on how to go about this? Also, if any other problems are obvious then please ignore them as I'll figure those out myself, I just need help with the `spawn` command.

Below is my expect script($USER & $PASS are passed from a different bash script)

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
log_file expectLog.log ;#
cd ~/customDirectory
source ~/.bashrc
spawn customCommandName param1 param2
expect -exact "User Name:"
send -- $USER
expect -exact "Password:"
send -- $PASS
```

Comment: `expect` is based on TCL, a totally different programming language. You can't `source ~/.bashrc` in an `expect` script any more than you can in a C++ or Java program. Instead, make a shell script that runs your custom command and invoke that as an external program

Comment: @thatotherguy this worked for me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to launch an interactive bash shell (that reads the .bashrc) to run the function:

```
spawn bash -ic "customCommandName param1 param2"
```

Don't forget to hit enter when sending stuff:

```
send -- "$USER\r"
```

Where does the $USER variable come from? If it's an environment variable, do this

```
send -- "$env(USER)\r"
```

Comment: I ended up using @thatotherguy's solution but I also used the environment variable recommendation you made, thank you.